# How to implement double tap and drag?

Tags: java, android

I am building a remote mouse app for android.I currently have the mouse and click working.I am now trying to implement a double tap and drag to represent the click and drag on the computer.I have not been able to use the default functions of OnGestureListener nor OnDoubleTapListener.

I am using the onScroll method to get the finger movement and send it over using HTTP Requests to a server running on the computer

```
   @Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    String my_url = "http://192.168.1.3:8500/"+(int)distanceX+"+"+(int)distanceY;
    new MyHttpRequestTask().execute(my_url,"");
    return true;
}
```

and onSingleTapUp for click event

```
  @Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    new MyHttpRequestTask().execute("http://192.168.1.3:8500/click","");
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement double click and drag?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the double tap is not the best gesture for this operation... but if you want this, you can use the OnDoubleTapListener ([see the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener)) for the double tap detection and, if you want, you can use the same "onScroll" method (I suggest to override the "onTouchEvent" instead) to manage the drag. In this case you have to know if the onScroll is called after a single or a double tap. You can use a enum like that:

```
private enum State{NORMAL, DOUBLETAPPED}
private State s=State.NORMAL;
```

Now, in your OnDoubleTapListener you have to say "Hey! I've performed a Double tap".

```
@Override
onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e){
    s=State.DOUBLETAPPED;
}
```

And so you can manage the scroll in the right way:

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float, distanceY) {
    if(s.equals(State.DOUBLETAPPED))
        //do what you want
    return true;
}
```

Don't forget to do `s=State.NORMAL;` when you detect a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`!

Comment: Interesting solution you have there.Unfortunately,the problem seems to be with onDoubleTapEvent,when i double tap and drag my finger on the screen, the code on onScroll does't execute,meaning it doesn't send the finger position to the server.